# How can I move within a block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to move within a block, to get to the perfect vantage point from which to look outside thru a window in one direction and a door off to the side.

When I am up against a wall, I can hold <kbd>W</kbd> to slide a bit in one direction or another. But if there is nothing in front of me, <kbd>W</kbd> always moves out of the current block.

Is there another way to fine-tune my position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just walking to the right point is too fast for you, there are ways of slowing it down. Crouching, drawing a bow, walking on soulsand, getting stuck in cobweb, potion of slowness, potion of turtle master, a bunch of other less practical ones. Also, combining them all reduces speed further.

Comment: The other answers are great extensions to the basic idea, but this one captures the most basic answer for a newbie like me: crouch!  Just hold the shift key down while moving with w/a/s/d. This slows things down and causes movement to not immediately leave the current block. It is still faster movement than I like, so I'll explore some of the other approaches here, but just crouching is a huge step forward (heh).

Comment: @nealmcb Check the edit. I completely forgot about the bow. Crouching with bow drawn is even slower.

Answer (score 3):

Break the blocks on the floor around you except for the one you want to stand on. Hold crouch and you won't leave the block when moving around because crouching stops you from falling into gaps. Found the perfect vantage? Leave your keyboard and use your mouse to replace the blocks.

Try a variety of block selections to use as your balance.

Comment: Hmm - very creative and instructive! But I'd prefer something less destructive. This vantage point is in my  base and I don't want to destroy the stuff around me.

Comment: I've added another idea to the pot. I'm leaving this as an option for others.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, from the comments on your previous answer, you would prefer not to break blocks around you. If temporary destruction isn't an option, try temporary construction instead.

Instead of breaking blocks around you, place blocks around you. You can then walk up to them and fine-tune your position, then break them afterwards. Also try using other types of blocks to press up against like fence posts, and open trapdoors. This will allow different points.

*(I'll be honest, I'm throwing ideas at the wall to see what sticks. Hopefully one of these method works for you.)*

Comment: Thanks again - more great points for maximum flexibility. In my case, I'm right next to a bed, so I don't want to put something on top of it, or have to construct stuff all around me, so just crouching is my first go-to-move.